# can i clone my project source from svn repository to Git repository

Tags: git, svn, repository, git-svn

SVN repository in: `svn://server/myPath/svn/repos`

Git repository in: `git://server/myPath/git/repos`

I'm trying to clone the svn project so I used this command: 
git svn clone svn://zone.spip.org/spip-zone gitzone

and I got a strange error message:
error: git-svn died of signal 6

Comment: http://bit.ly/Xn5kvG may help you

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to keep the code in SVN why don't you just

git svn clone svn://server/myPath/svn/repos

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnNY's answer says, you can do `git svn clone`, and later keep up with the SVN repo by `git svn rebase`. Do read the `git svn` documentation, there are several useful subcommands (and important caveats!) when interacting with SVN. `git svn clone` is slow as molasses (yes, a modest size repository can well take more than a day!); if several people need access, clone once and distribute e.g. tarballs of the cloned repository. Or ditch SVN. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone your old SVN repo and then move it into git I did it the following why.

```
git svn clone svn://server/myPath/svn/repos/trunk myproject.git
```

or

```
git svn clone -s svn://server/myPath/svn/repos myproject.git
```

then

```
cd myproject.git
```

I did NOT want the history so I then removed the git folder

```
rm -rf .git/
```

then

```
git init
git add .
git commit -a
git remote add origin git@git:<project>.git
git push -u origin master
```

and your now done and ready to use it as git